# Multiple rectangles on scatter chart using d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I have a scatter chart. I need to draw multiple rectangles via mouse drag on the scatter chart.

I know how to draw a single rectangle or selection on the chart.

Is this possible using d3.js

Also i would like to know whether it's possible to draw polygons via mouse drag on a scatter chart using d3.js ?

Comment: Post some of your code.